# Browser Crashed in Natty

Tags: package-management, firefox

My system froze while I was installing ubuntu-restricted-extras in natty. So I restarted. After that firefox crashed and it is not properly showing websites. Same goes for the chromium browser. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned.

Answer (score 2):

Open a terminal and run:

```
sudo apt-get install -f
```

Comment: Its not working.When i run the command,i get "0 upgraded,0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 38 not upgraded".